# "Axios POST Request to API Endpoint Results in Internal Server Error 500"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, axios, openai-api

[Here is the github repository](https://github.com/Lordyasith/saas)

[HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT OF THE ERROR SHOWN IN THE CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEEiM.png)

Problem:

When making a POST request to the /api/conversation endpoint in my Next.js application using Axios, I consistently receive an "Internal Server Error 500" response. This error occurs when attempting to interact with the OpenAI API and seems to be related to the communication between my application and the OpenAI service.

Code:

page.tsx (Frontend):

```
"use client";

import * as z from "zod";
import { Heading } from "@/components/heading";

import { MessageSquare } from "lucide-react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { formSchema } from "./constants";
import {zodResolver} from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ChatCompletionRequestMessage } from "openai";

const ConversationPage=()=>{
    const router=useRouter();
    const [messages,setMessages]=useState<ChatCompletionRequestMessage[]>([]);
    const form= useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver:zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues:{
            prompt:""
        }
    });

    const isLoading=form.formState.isSubmitting;
    const onSubmit=async(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>)=>{
        try{
            const userMessage:ChatCompletionRequestMessage={
                role:"user",
                content:values.prompt,
            };
            const newMessages=[...messages,userMessage];
            const response=await axios.post("/api/conversation",{
                messages:newMessages,
            });
            setMessages((current)=>[...current,userMessage,response.data]);
            form.reset();
        } catch(error:any){
            console.log(error)
        } finally{
            router.refresh();
        }
    };
    return(
        
        <div>
            <Heading
            title="Conversation"
            description="Our most advanced conversation model."
            icon={MessageSquare}
            iconColor="text-violet-500"
            bgColor="bg-violet-500/10"
            />
            <div className="px-4 lg:px-8">
                <div>
                    <Form {...form}>
                        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="rounded-lg border w-full p-4 px-3 md:px-6 focus-within:shadow-sm grid grid-cols-12 gap-2">
                        <FormField name="prompt" render={({field})=>(<FormItem className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-10">
                            <FormControl className="m-0 p-0">
                                <Input className="border-0 outline-none
                                focus-visible:ring-0
                                focus-visible:ring-transparent" disabled={isLoading} placeholder="How do i calculate the radius of circle?"{...field}/>
                            </FormControl>
                        </FormItem>)}/>
                        <Button className="col-span-12 lg:col-span-2 w-full" disabled={isLoading}>Generate</Button>
                        </form>

                    </Form>
                </div>
                <div className="space-y-4 mt-4">
                    <div className="flex flex-col-reverse gap-y-4">
                        {messages.map((message)=>(
                            <div key={message.content}>{message.content}
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default ConversationPage;
`

/api/conversation (Backend):
```

```
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration=new Configuration({
    apiKey:process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai=new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export async function POST(
    req:Request
){
    try{
        const {userId}=auth();
        const body=await req.json();
        const {messages}=body;
        if(!userId){
            return new NextResponse("Unauthorized",{status:401});
        }
        if(!configuration.apiKey){
            return new NextResponse("OpenAI API Key not configured",{status:500});
        }
        if (!messages){
            return new NextResponse("Message are required",{status:400});
        }
        const response=await openai.createChatCompletion({
            model:"gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages
        });
        return NextResponse.json(response.data.choices[0].message);

    }catch(error){
        console.log("[CONVERSATION_ERROR]");
        return new NextResponse("Internal error",{status:500})
    }
}
```

Error Details:

The error message received in the browser's console when making the Axios POST request is as follows:

POST http://localhost:3000/api/conversation 500 (Internal Server Error)
The AxiosError object provides additional details, including the message "Request failed with status code 500," indicating that the server responded with an internal server error.

GitHub Repository:

For those interested in taking a closer look at my code, here's a link to my GitHub repository:https://github.com/Lordyasith/saas

Steps Taken:

I've carefully reviewed and confirmed the correctness of my server-side code in the /api/conversation endpoint. The code includes constructing the API request to OpenAI, error handling, and response handling.

I've verified that my OpenAI API key is correctly set in the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable and is accessible within my server-side code.

I've confirmed that the format of the POST request matches the expected format according to the OpenAI API documentation.

I've enhanced error handling by adding console.log statements at various stages of the Axios request, both before and after the API call, to better understand where the issue might be occurring.

Request for Assistance:

I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Are there any common pitfalls when integrating Axios with external APIs that might lead to this type of error? What additional steps can I take to diagnose the root cause of the "Internal Server Error" and successfully interact with the OpenAI API?

Thank you for your time and assistance in advance.

Comment: You need to share the error or some logs from server to figure out what the error is.

Comment: @RobinThomas  Thank you for the response.I have added a screenshot of the error shown in the console.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community i shared my github repository